# How to sort in View by last modified/change date - fields not visible in sort criteria

Tags: 7, views, nodes, datetime

I'd like to sort content type by the last modified/changed/updated date of content but cannot choose the last modified/changed/updated date in the sort criteria. How can I do this, please? See screenshot:

[image]

I've done many things with Views so am surprised that I am puzzled by this one, it seems to be a simple problem - with, hopefully an obvious answer (and a quick win of rep points from a fellow drupal stackexchanger :) )

Comment: It doesn't look like standard node views, it says "Indexed node" so obviously the sort handler for this type is missing the date fields.